# Ordering results in show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got two models - service_request_work_plan where service_request_work_plan has_many work_plan_tasks and work_plan_tasks belongs to service_request_work_plan.  The linkage works, associations render properly and I have the code below in my show view for service_reqeust_work_plan, the goal of which is to show the work_plan_tasks in order.  The show action works properly, but they are not showing in order (i.e. order_of_exeuction).  What am I missing?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Order of Execution</th>
    <th>Task</th>
    <th>SLO</th>
    <th>Task Instructions</th>
  </tr>
  <% @service_request_work_plan.work_plan_tasks.each do |work_plan_task| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= work_plan_task.order_of_execution %></td>
      <td><%= work_plan_task.task_name %></td>
      <td><%= work_plan_task.task_slo %></td>
      <td><%= work_plan_task.task_instructions %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

class ServiceRequestWorkPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :testing_company_id, :work_plan_name, :work_plan_comments
  belongs_to :testing_company
  has_many :work_plan_tasks
end

class WorkPlanTask < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :testing_company_id, :task_name, :task_instructions, :service_request_work_plan_id, :task_slo, :order_of_execution
  belongs_to :testing_company
  belongs_to :service_request_work_plan

end

  def show
    @service_request_work_plan = ServiceRequestWorkPlan.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Comment: The first step would be looking at where you defined your instance variable `@service_request_work_plan` to see how you ordered your ActiveRecord query. The second step would be looking at your model to see if you have any default scopes defined. Could you share those pieces of code?

Comment: Thanks for the response - just posted both models in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.order(order_of_execution: :asc)` for `work_plan_tasks` when querying the database from the controller. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering

Controller:

```
def show
  @service_request_work_plan = ServiceRequestWorkPlan.find(params[:id]).work_plan_tasks.order(order_of_execution: :asc)
end
```

Comment: HM1 - thanks for the response.  I read the page you referenced, but wasn't clear in what file to add the able code to (sorry for the noob question).

Comment: I added it and now I get an exception error - undefined method 'order', any ideas?

Comment: Now I get a NoMethod error for private method select?

Comment: oops, I missed it was supposed to order the `work_plan_tasks` and not the single object of `ServiceRequestWorkPlan`. See updated code.

Comment: I think we crossed posts - I added the updated code (with the select statement) and got a NoMethod error for private method select.

Comment: Sorry about that. I removed `select()` and tried it on one of my models. This should work. See updated statement above.

Comment: It accepted that code, but now it says it doesn't know who the testing company is.  Do you think I have to expand the code to accommodate for all variables in the show action or do you think I'm better off creating a new action (e.g. show2) that shows the tasks?  (and if the later - any direction would be appreciated).  I'll give you props for the response either way though :)

Comment: It's unclear as to what you mean by "it doesn't know who the testing company is" because I don't see where you use `testing_company` in the table above. Its probably clear to you but I can't see your outputs and any code additions you may have done to what's displayed above. This is looking like a separate question and is better handled as such.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
<% @service_request_work_plan.work_plan_tasks.each do |work_plan_task| %>
```

into this line:

```
<% @service_request_work_plan.work_plan_tasks.all.order(:order_of_execution).each do |work_plan_task| %>
```

Default order is ascending, so the above line is complete. If you need descending order:

```
order(:order_of_execution => :desc)
```

Comment: Tried it - now I get an undefined method 'order'